# Reading a string from app.config file

Tags: c#

My question isn't related to the connection string which is the most popular. The other only help I could find with this is someone not using the reference.

What I'm trying to do: I have a string stored in the app.config file, which looks like:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <App_5.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="Location_Name" serializeAs="String">
      <value>String I want</value>
    </setting>
```

My code to pull the string is:

```
string Loc_Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Location_Name"];
```

I have the reference added, and used. When I run the program my return is always `null`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are storing it in the wrong place in the app.config. For single name/value pairs use the `appSettings`. Then your retrieval code in the question will work.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Location_Name" value="String I want" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code (repeated from question)

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Location_Name"];
```